# JSON pay load dict to DataFrame

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary

I have the data in the below form

```
json_df([
    {"a1": "A", "b1": "B", "c1": "C"},
    {"a2": "A", "b2": "B", "c2": "C"},
    {"a3": "A", "b3": "B", "c3": "C"},
    {"a4": "A", "b4": "B", "c4": "C"}
])
```

The expected output is

```
A   B   C
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c2
a3  b3  c3
a4  b4  c4
```

I tried the below

```
def json_df(data):
    data = pd.DataFrame([dict([(v,k) for (k,v) in ele.items()]) for ele in data],index=None)
    return data
```

the output I got is

```
    A   B   C
0   a1  b1  c1
1   a2  b2  c2
2   a3  b3  c3
3   a4  b4  c4
```

I don't want to have the index. I tried various ways to get rid of the index but no luck.

Comment: You can't. why you want *to get rid of the index*?

Comment: A dataframe has an index. Full stop. But you can choose not to display it: `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: it's part of a test and I'm asked to produce the output exactly same as given by the test case

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"A" : ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'], "B": ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'], "C": ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("A", inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     B   C
A
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c2
a3  b3  c3
a4  b4  c4
```